# AWS Cloud9 Server refuses to connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, web, server, cloud9-ide

So I'm trying to make a website for school and I've been following [this](https://upskillcourses.com/courses/essential-web-developer-course) guys tutorial on how to make a website.  But for some reason when I get to lesson [32](https://upskillcourses.com/courses/essential-web-developer-course/2-turn-cloud9-into-a-server) and I enter the `ec2-user:~/environment/blog $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT command`, the website doesnt run and it says " somenumbersandletters.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com refused to connect " with an error. I've followed all the steps correctly (Except for the directory he runs it from, I run it straight from blog instead of environment because it tells me I need to make a new app the other way). I've tried disabling my firewall, I've enabled Cookies and searched the internet for a solution. I am very new to Servers and Coding and any help would be greatly appreciated!
[This](https://pastebin.com/exCJBtm9) is my Terminal Log

Comment: Do your security groups allow inbound connections from your server?

Comment: Yeah they do I think. I'm not entirely sure though

Answer (score 12):

Answer from https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/cwnbt1/aws_cloud9_server_refuses_to_connect/

Once you start the rails server, click the 'preview' button. When this tells you that it refuses to connect, find the button that looks like two overlapping squares with an arrow to "pop out into a new window." Once it was in a new tab, it worked like a charm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know it was quite a while ago this answer, but it still works, I would have never figured this out!, thanks @Sunshine!

Comment: Awesome thanks! This was about my fifth error in a row trying to get something working on cloud9 (errors installing Postgres and then problems with the IP whitelisting) and I was about to abandon ship - so thanks very much!!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue as well. I could view my rails application when viewing it from within a new tab, but not within the Cloud 9 IDE tab.

If you look in the browser console when viewing through the tab, you will see this error:

`Refused to display 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.vfs.cloud9.xxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

This error is being caused because you are viewing the rails application through an iFrame via the Cloud 9 IDE. By default to add security and hinder Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks, Rails sets `SAMEORIGIN` for the `X-Fram-Options` header. This will not allow the rails app to be visible in the Cloud 9 IDE tab using the iFrame.

In order to bypass this, you will need to set this header to use `ALLOWALL` instead.

**NOTE: Only do this within your development environment and never in a production environment. This could open your site up to XSS attacks.**

Add the following configuration option to your `config/environments/development.rb` file:

```rb
  config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
  }
```

After saving the changes, restart your rails server and the application should now be visible within the Cloud 9 IDE tab directly.

Comment: @brismith I am glad you found it helpful. Did it solve your issue?

Comment: What about django applications? I have similar issue with django application